# C++: How to assign member value in nested optional struct?

Tags: c++

I wish to understand how I can assign member values to an optional (child) struct. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

struct Root
{
    struct Parent
    {
        struct Child
        {
            int value2 = 0;
        };
        
        int value1 = 0;
        std::optional<Child> child = std::nullopt;
    };
    
    std::optional<Parent> parent = std::nullopt;
};

int main() {
    Root root;
    root.parent.value1 = 19;
    root.parent.child.value2 = 21;
    // root.parent.child.value = std::optional<int>(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are on the tipping point of making your struct a class (due to complexity). So I would say by an accessors (getter/setters) in the outer class... That is if you want to be able to refactor the inners of the class later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (root.parent->child.has_value()) {
    root.parent->child->value2 = 21;
} else {
    root.parent->child = Root::Parent::Child();
    root.parent->child->value2 = 21;
}
```

You can first check with the `.has_value()` function if it is initialised or not and then assign the value.